# Ember data model raises loadedData

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I can't figure out why I have this exception:

Uncaught Error: Attempted to handle event `loadedData`on  while in state root.loaded.updated.uncommitted.

This is my controller which causes this exception:

```
App.TodosNewController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({
  create: function(todo) {
    var self = this;

    todo.on('becameInvalid', function(todo) {
      self.set('model', todo);
    });

    todo.on('didCreate', function() {
      self.set('priority', '');
      self.set('title', '');
      self.set('due_date', '');
      self.transitionToRoute('todos'); // This line raises exception!
    });
    todo.save();
  }
});
```

But it's interesting that this code works well but it's buggy - it can create a lot of model records on memory:

```
App.TodosNewController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({
  create: function() {
    var data = this.getProperties('title', 'priority', 'due_date');
    var todo = App.Todo.createRecord(data);

    var self = this;

    todo.on('becameInvalid', function(todo) {
      self.set('model', todo);
    });

    todo.on('didCreate', function() {
      self.set('priority', '');
      self.set('title', '');
      self.set('due_date', '');
      self.transitionToRoute('todos');
    });
    todo.save();
  }
});
```

Thank you, folks, for your response.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to delete these lines:

```
  self.set('priority', '');
  self.set('title', '');
  self.set('due_date', '');
```